# Postgres Decrypt in sql

Tags: postgresql

I am having a problem creating a libraries on codeigniter and postgres. My problem is that on my query on postgres I've encrypted the that is.

```
$sql = "INSERT table ('text') Values(encrypt('example','mysecret','aes'))
```

when querying to decrypt so I used this code

```
SELECT decrypt(text,'mysecret','aes') from table
```

The displays on the query is okay, it decrypts but when going to foreach.

```
foreach($result as $key){
echo $key->text;
endforeach;
```

The results are encrypted, I wonder why what i did wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The usage of the raw encrypt/decrypt functions is discouraged (in your case, look at point 4):

> These functions only run a cipher over data; they don't have any
>   advanced features of PGP encryption. Therefore they have some major
>   problems:
>
> 1. They use user key directly as cipher key.
> 2. They don't provide any integrity checking, to see if the encrypted
>      data was modified.
> 3. They expect that users manage all encryption parameters themselves,
>      even IV.
> 4. They don't handle text.
>
> So, with the introduction of PGP encryption, usage of raw encryption
>   functions is discouraged.

Instead you should use the PGP functions.

Comment: do you have some samples on how to use the query , please advise i'm not yet familiar with postges functions equivalent to mysql

Comment: I've encountered some issues like ( ERROR: decrypt error: Data not a multiple of block size ) does this means these IV would be one of the main problem for decrypt functions? These may be problem in the near future.Great to have an advice

Comment: @boyee: the docs provide some examples: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/pgcrypto.html I'm not that well versed with the MySQL encryption functions but I can tell you that it's generally a bad idea to provide your encryption/decryption key in the query. It allows people reading the logs and all to see your encryption key making it effectively useless. This document provides some inforation and PGP examples: http://www.postgresonline.com/journal/archives/165-Encrypting-data-with-pgcrypto.html

Comment: Very frustrating finding an answer that tells me not to use encrypt, when I need to decrypt data that is already encrypted with the raw functions. This should have been a comment, not an answer.

Comment: @oxguy3: it really shouldn't be a comment, the official Postgres manual recommends against using the functions in this manner so it's a valid answer. I understand how annoying it can be since you apparently stumbled upon code that's using it in a "bad" way but it's still a bad idea.